# Speech on signing in

Tags: 20.04, sound, login, password

ubuntu 20.04 How do I stop my LENOVO laptop saying "black circle, black circle, black circle ... paddle" when I enter my password at start up ?

Comment: Click on the power icon in the login screen, and disable text to speech

Comment: Thanks   Problem sorted